# multi variables search in mysql database

Tags: php

i asked the question before but it got closed because it was unclear post, anyway im now trying to ask in a clear way.

i have a car service company, so we sell tyres aswell and i want to create a filterable search method in the website, for example the customer will search for specific values from the options, like he will search for all manufacturers but he want summer tires, the width 150, profil is 40, diameter is 16 and the rest he will select the all option. and so on...

html code:

```
<label for="manufacturer"><strong>manufacturer:</strong></label>
                                <select id="manufacturer">
                                    <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                    <option value="option1">BF Goodrich</option>
                                    <option value="option2">Continental</option>
                                    <option value="option3">Michelin</option>
                                    <option value="option4">Pirelli</option>
                                </select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="model"><strong>tyretype:</strong></label>
                                <select id="model">
                                    <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                    <option value="option1">Summer tyre</option>
                                    <option value="option2">winter tyre</option>
                                    <option value="option3">winter tyre 2</option>
                                </select>
                            </li>
                            <li class="select-two">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="min-price"><strong>width:</strong></label>
                                    <select id="min-price">
                                        <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                        <option value="option1">145</option>
                                        <option value="option2">150</option>
                                        <option value="option3">155</option>
                                        <option value="option3">160</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="max-price"><strong>Profil:</strong></label>
                                    <select id="max-price">
                                        <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                        <option value="option1">30</option>
                                        <option value="option2">35</option>
                                        <option value="option3">40</option>
                                        <option value="option3">45</option
                                    </select>                   
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="select-two">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="min-price"><strong>Diameter:</strong></label>
                                    <select id="min-price">
                                        <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                        <option value="option1">13"</option>
                                        <option value="option2">14"</option>
                                        <option value="option3">15"</option>
                                        <option value="option3">16"</option>
                                        <option value="option3">17"</option>
                                        <option value="option3">18"</option>
                                        <option value="option3">19"</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="max-price"><strong>Maximum load:</strong></label>
                                    <select id="max-price">
                                        <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                        <option value="option1">75</option>
                                        <option value="option2">76</option>
                                        <option value="option3">77</option>
                                        <option value="option3">78</option>
                                        <option value="option3">79</option>
                                        <option value="option3">80</option>
                                        <option value="option3">81</option>
                                        <option value="option3">82</option>
                                        <option value="option3">83</option>
                                        <option value="option3">84</option>
                                    </select>                   
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <label for="engine"><strong>Maximum speed:</strong></label>
                                <select id="engine">
                                    <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                    <option value="option1">Q = max 160 km/h</option>
                                    <option value="option2">R = max 170 km/h</option>
                                    <option value="option3">S = max 180 km/h</option>
                                    <option value="option3">T = max 190 km/h</option>
                                    <option value="option3">H = max 210 km/h</option>
                                </select>
                            </li>
```

in mysql database i have a table called tyres which includes the following columns,

manufacturer,
tyretype,
width,
length,
profil,
diameter,
maximum load,
maximum speed,
tyreprice.

i cant come up with good search query that includes all the search options listed above and fetches information correctly from mysql database.

Comment: i searched for php query examples, but i couldnt find what i want. so i thought maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tyres WHERE 1==1";

if ($_POST['manufacturer'] != 'ALL'){
   $sql = $sql . ' AND manufacturer==' . $_POST['manufacturer'];
}
if ($_POST['model'] != 'ALL'){
   $sql = $sql . ' AND model==' . $_POST['model'];
}
 //etc etc
```

So basically you only add AND clauses to your WHERE if necessary, which only happens if something other than 'ALL' is selected.

You'll need to add a value to your default ALL select menus like so:

```
<select id="manufacturer">
   <option value ="ALL" selected="selected">All</option>
   <option value="option1">BF Goodrich</option>
   <option value="option2">Continental</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tyres WHERE manufacturer='".$_POST['manufacturer']."' AND tyretype='".$_POST['tyretype']."' AND ...etc..");
```

more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html
If you're having problem i'm here :)

If he select all option you make an if like this:

```
<?
if ($_POST['tyretype'] == "all") 
{  // then do the same query you can see above without this part "AND tyretype='".$_POST['tyretype']."'"
}
?>
```

Comment: this does not satisfy the 'ALL' case

Comment: no. The manufature column in the database will not hold 'ALL' as data values. You need to selectively add WHERE clauses iff the select is not 'ALL'

Comment: lol you just copied from mine, however is not necessary $sql = "SELECT * FROM tyres WHERE 1==1";
where 1==1 is not useful

Comment: I posted before you edited, as in like 3 min before u edited (hover over timestamps if you don't believe me). And you are wrong again. The WHERE 1==1 makes the if statement logic look cleaner. Otherwise you will have to check only for first one to include WHERE. You should pay attention to other answers / refresh before making accusations.

Comment: and it should be != all and you don't post any actual modification to the sql, how could this have been a copy off of you when i gave you the right answer anyway haha, sit down.